# Multi-label stratified split

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel, train-test-split

I am working on a multilabel text classification problem.

The text data is called 'cleaned_text' and has shape (92259, 1) and the one-hot encoded label data is called 'labels' and has shape (92259, 32).  The text is consists of the text from MathOverflow questions and answers with latex and stopwords removed.  The labels consist of 32 arxiv tags (such as 'ag.algebraic-geometry').

I want to make a train/test split which respects label co-occurences.

Initially I just used sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.1, random_state = 42)
for train_index, test_index in rs.split(cleaned_text, labels):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    cleaned_text_train_ss, cleaned_text_test_ss = cleaned_text[train_index], cleaned_text[test_index]
    labels_train_ss, labels_test_ss = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]
```

I then visualized the co-occurrence tables as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_coocurence_ss = np.dot(labels_train_ss.transpose(),labels_train_ss)
test_coocurence_ss = np.dot(labels_test_ss.transpose(),labels_test_ss)

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(train_coocurence_ss*1.0/np.max(train_coocurence_ss, axis = 0), interpolation='nearest')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(test_coocurence_ss*1.0/np.max(test_coocurence_ss, axis = 0), interpolation='nearest')


plt.show()
```

This results in the following image:

[image: co-occurrence matrix of train and test labels using sklearn]

These looks fairly similar, and in fact if I compare each of these I get at most a $10\%$ difference in these tables:

```
difference_ss = train_coocurence_ss*1.0/np.max(train_coocurence_ss, axis = 0) - test_coocurence_ss*1.0/np.max(test_coocurence_ss, axis = 0)
difference_ss.min(), difference_ss.max()
```

returns (-0.09994714587737841, 0.07527291190657531).

I was wondering if I could get better performance using [this multilabel split tool](https://github.com/trent-b/iterative-stratification) as described in [this article](https://medium.com/gumgum-tech/creating-balanced-multi-label-datasets-for-model-training-and-evaluation-16b6a3a2d912).  So I tried the following:

```
from iterstrat.ml_stratifiers import MultilabelStratifiedShuffleSplit
msss = MultilabelStratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.1, random_state = 42)
for train_index, test_index in msss.split(cleaned_text, labels):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    cleaned_text_train, cleaned_text_test = cleaned_text[train_index], cleaned_text[test_index]
    labels_train, labels_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

train_coocurence = np.dot(labels_train.transpose(),labels_train)
test_coocurence = np.dot(labels_test.transpose(),labels_test)
```

I get very similar looking plots:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(train_coocurence*1.0/np.max(train_coocurence, axis = 0), interpolation='nearest')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(test_coocurence*1.0/np.max(test_coocurence, axis = 0), interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

[image: co-occurrence matrix of train and test labels using trent-b/iterative-stratification]

When I test the difference the same way I actually get slightly worse performance!

```
difference = train_coocurence*1.0/np.max(train_coocurence, axis = 0) - test_coocurence*1.0/np.max(test_coocurence, axis = 0)
difference.min(),difference.max()
```

returns (-0.11853497379813172, 0.10523731587561375)

So finally I come to my **questions**:  Is there a flaw in [trent-b/iterative-stratification](https://github.com/trent-b/iterative-stratification)?  Am I using it incorrectly?  Or did I just happen to get really lucky with my sklearn ShuffleSplit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was nothing wrong with my code, and the solution provided by trent-b/iterative-stratification is superior to the sklearn version.

When I scale both training co-occurrence matrices to have the same totals as their respective training co-occurrence matrices, the iterativel-stratification matrices are much closer than the sklearn versions.

My error was in attempting to assess the performance of these two methods by subtracting the scaled matrices.  In retrospect this isn't really the performance measure I should have been interested in (although they do make pretty pictures).